# How to show the details from two models in same form view or calendar view in odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo-8

My model is as follows

```
class Book_MRoom(models.Model):
    _name="book.meeting"
    #_inherit = 'meeting.room'

    name=fields.Char(string="Enter booking person name",required=True)
    company_name=fields.Many2one('company','Enter your company name',required=True)
    start_time=fields.Datetime(string="Starting date",select=True,required=True)
    end_time=fields.Datetime(string="Ending date",select=True)
        meeting_room=fields.Many2one('mroom', 'select the room')

class Book_DRoom(models.Model):
    _name="book.discussion"
    #_inherit = 'discussion.room'

    name=fields.Char(string="Enter booking person name",required=True)
    company_name=fields.Many2one('company','Enter your company name',required=True)
    start_time=fields.Datetime(string="Starting date",select=True,required=True)
    end_time=fields.Datetime(string="Ending date")
    discussion_room=fields.Many2one('droom','select the room')

class CompanyData(models.Model):
    _name="company"
        _rec_name='companyname'

    companyname=fields.Char(string="Enter the name of the company")
    companyID=fields.Char(string="Enter the ID of company")`
```

My viewes file is as follows

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="meeting-calender">
   <field name="name">meeting-calender-view</field>
   <field name="model">company</field>
   <field name="type">calendar</field>
   <field name="arch" type="xml">
      <calendar string="bookingstatus" date_start="start_time" date_stop="end_time" display="[name]">
          <field name="meeting_room"/>
          <field name="name"/>
          <field name="companyname"/>
      </calendar>
   </field>
 </record>
```

In my calendar view i have specified company as my model. But in calendar view i need to use the fields of book.meeting and book.discussion models. How is it possible?

Comment: Why dont you add both meeting and discussiong as a many2one on company?

Comment: @dccdany Can you please help me, How can i do that?

Comment: Sure, in the class companyData, add two more fields:

    fields.Many2one('book.discussion', 'Book discussion')
    fields.Many2one('book.meeting', 'Book meeting')

add also them in the views and for each company you have 1 book discussion and 1 book meeting. Add both in form and calendar view.

tell me if u need anything else

Comment: @dccdany Suppose if i add a field like this fields.Many2one('book.discussion', 'Book discussion') , How will i distinguish the fields of book.discussion and use those fields separately?

Comment: what do you really need?, do you need a related meeting and discussion for 1 date in that company?

Comment: Suppose if i have created a many2one field of book.meeting in company model, how will i use it refer start_time and end_time (fields of book.meeting) in the XML file record (as company as model)

Comment: You can create related fields in company if you need to see them

Comment: @dccdany, I have already created related fields and i am able to use these fields to refer the fields from other model. But i am not able to use the related fields in XML to refer other fields of the model for example start_time and end_time from other module , i.e. 'book.meeting'

Comment: You cant do that. First of all you need to define what model you need to see in calendar view (lets say company). Lets say that a company can have a lot of meetings and discussions, but what you need is the date of each meeting and discussion, then, what you need is the calendar view of Meeting and / or discussion, not the company one